# Highchart Heatmap - DateTime Y Axis Alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, highcharts, heatmap

I'm attempting to create a heat map using Highcharts, with datetime x-axis and y-axis.

All is looking good except the alignment of the y-axis.

The "00:00" should be at the very base of the chart but it's offset/centered to the first box.

I've looked around but can't work out what settings I need to fiddle with. Any help appreciated.

Please see my jsFiddle example below. The data array contains `[EpochTicksForStartOfDay, TicksForTimeOfDay, Value]`

https://jsfiddle.net/h2zb2tos/5/

UPDATE:  I'd like the y-axis lines and labels to align with the bottom of the heatmap boxes. The 1st (lowest) boxes "start" at 00:00, the 2nd at 01:00, the 3rd at 02:00 etc. so I'd expect the lines to line up.

**Html**

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 800px; min-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

  var json = {
    "Data": [
      [1453075200000, 0, 45.0000],
      [1453075200000, 3600000, 46.0000],
      [1453075200000, 7200000, 47.0000],
      [1453075200000, 10800000, 48.0000],
      [1453075200000, 14400000, 47.0000],
      [1453075200000, 18000000, 46.0000],
      [1453075200000, 21600000, 45.0000],
      [1453075200000, 25200000, 46.0000],
      [1453075200000, 28800000, 42.0000],
      [1453075200000, 32400000, 43.0000],
      [1453075200000, 36000000, 49.0000],
      [1453075200000, 39600000, 42.0000],
      [1453075200000, 43200000, 43.0000],
      [1453075200000, 46800000, 46.0000],
      [1453075200000, 50400000, 44.0000],
      [1453075200000, 54000000, 44.0000],
      [1453075200000, 57600000, 43.0000],
      [1453075200000, 61200000, 41.0000],
      [1453075200000, 64800000, 41.0000],
      [1453075200000, 68400000, 40.0000],
      [1453075200000, 72000000, 45.0000],
      [1453075200000, 75600000, 43.0000],
      [1453075200000, 79200000, 43.0000],
      [1453075200000, 82800000, 45.0000],
      [1453161600000, 0, 41.0000],
      [1453161600000, 3600000, 42.0000],
      [1453161600000, 7200000, 43.0000],
      [1453161600000, 10800000, 44.0000],
      [1453161600000, 14400000, 44.0000],
      [1453161600000, 18000000, 43.0000],
      [1453161600000, 21600000, 40.0000],
      [1453161600000, 25200000, 39.0000],
      [1453161600000, 28800000, 37.0000],
      [1453161600000, 32400000, 36.0000],
      [1453161600000, 36000000, 39.0000],
      [1453161600000, 39600000, 35.0000],
      [1453161600000, 43200000, 36.0000],
      [1453161600000, 46800000, 37.0000],
      [1453161600000, 50400000, 36.0000],
      [1453161600000, 54000000, 36.0000],
      [1453161600000, 57600000, 35.0000],
      [1453161600000, 61200000, 35.0000],
      [1453161600000, 64800000, 36.0000],
      [1453161600000, 68400000, 35.0000],
      [1453161600000, 72000000, 42.0000],
      [1453161600000, 75600000, 42.0000],
      [1453161600000, 79200000, 40.0000],
      [1453161600000, 82800000, 36.0000],
      [1453248000000, 0, 34.0000],
      [1453248000000, 3600000, 34.0000],
      [1453248000000, 7200000, 37.0000],
      [1453248000000, 10800000, 37.0000],
      [1453248000000, 14400000, 39.0000],
      [1453248000000, 18000000, 38.0000],
      [1453248000000, 21600000, 35.0000],
      [1453248000000, 25200000, 36.0000],
      [1453248000000, 28800000, 33.0000],
      [1453248000000, 32400000, 33.0000],
      [1453248000000, 36000000, 33.0000],
      [1453248000000, 39600000, 34.0000],
      [1453248000000, 43200000, 38.0000],
      [1453248000000, 46800000, 36.0000],
      [1453248000000, 50400000, 36.0000],
      [1453248000000, 54000000, 36.0000],
      [1453248000000, 57600000, 36.0000],
      [1453248000000, 61200000, 36.0000],
      [1453248000000, 64800000, 36.0000],
      [1453248000000, 68400000, 37.0000],
      [1453248000000, 72000000, 40.0000],
      [1453248000000, 75600000, 41.0000],
      [1453248000000, 79200000, 36.0000],
      [1453248000000, 82800000, 48.0000],
      [1453334400000, 0, 47.0000],
      [1453334400000, 3600000, 45.0000],
      [1453334400000, 7200000, 45.0000],
      [1453334400000, 10800000, 45.0000],
      [1453334400000, 14400000, 45.0000],
      [1453334400000, 18000000, 43.0000],
      [1453334400000, 21600000, 43.0000],
      [1453334400000, 25200000, 41.0000],
      [1453334400000, 28800000, 40.0000],
      [1453334400000, 32400000, 49.0000],
      [1453334400000, 36000000, 43.0000],
      [1453334400000, 39600000, 40.0000],
      [1453334400000, 43200000, 39.0000],
      [1453334400000, 46800000, 39.0000],
      [1453334400000, 50400000, 38.0000],
      [1453334400000, 54000000, 38.0000],
      [1453334400000, 57600000, 40.0000],
      [1453334400000, 61200000, 40.0000],
      [1453334400000, 64800000, 38.0000],
      [1453334400000, 68400000, 38.0000],
      [1453334400000, 72000000, 40.0000],
      [1453334400000, 75600000, 42.0000],
      [1453334400000, 79200000, 49.0000],
      [1453334400000, 82800000, 52.0000],
      [1453420800000, 0, 41.0000],
      [1453420800000, 3600000, 40.0000],
      [1453420800000, 7200000, 44.0000],
      [1453420800000, 10800000, 46.0000],
      [1453420800000, 14400000, 45.0000],
      [1453420800000, 18000000, 46.0000],
      [1453420800000, 21600000, 47.0000],
      [1453420800000, 25200000, 47.0000],
      [1453420800000, 28800000, 45.0000],
      [1453420800000, 32400000, 48.0000],
      [1453420800000, 36000000, 47.0000],
      [1453420800000, 39600000, 46.0000],
      [1453420800000, 43200000, 47.0000],
      [1453420800000, 46800000, 58.0000],
      [1453420800000, 50400000, 58.0000],
      [1453420800000, 54000000, 58.0000],
      [1453420800000, 57600000, 66.0000],
      [1453420800000, 61200000, 60.0000],
      [1453420800000, 64800000, 60.0000],
      [1453420800000, 68400000, 54.0000],
      [1453420800000, 72000000, 56.0000],
      [1453420800000, 75600000, 55.0000],
      [1453420800000, 79200000, 65.0000],
      [1453420800000, 82800000, 63.0000],
      [1453507200000, 0, 54.0000],
      [1453507200000, 3600000, 61.0000],
      [1453507200000, 7200000, 61.0000],
      [1453507200000, 10800000, 61.0000],
      [1453507200000, 14400000, 60.0000],
      [1453507200000, 18000000, 60.0000],
      [1453507200000, 21600000, 56.0000],
      [1453507200000, 25200000, 57.0000],
      [1453507200000, 28800000, 53.0000],
      [1453507200000, 32400000, 54.0000],
      [1453507200000, 36000000, 56.0000],
      [1453507200000, 39600000, 56.0000],
      [1453507200000, 43200000, 60.0000],
      [1453507200000, 46800000, 63.0000],
      [1453507200000, 50400000, 59.0000],
      [1453507200000, 54000000, 58.0000],
      [1453507200000, 57600000, 57.0000],
      [1453507200000, 61200000, 59.0000],
      [1453507200000, 64800000, 58.0000],
      [1453507200000, 68400000, 58.0000],
      [1453507200000, 72000000, 54.0000],
      [1453507200000, 75600000, 54.0000],
      [1453507200000, 79200000, 57.0000],
      [1453507200000, 82800000, 53.0000],
      [1453593600000, 0, 54.0000],
      [1453593600000, 3600000, 54.0000],
      [1453593600000, 7200000, 56.0000],
      [1453593600000, 10800000, 57.0000],
      [1453593600000, 14400000, 57.0000],
      [1453593600000, 18000000, 55.0000],
      [1453593600000, 21600000, 56.0000],
      [1453593600000, 25200000, 57.0000],
      [1453593600000, 28800000, 55.0000],
      [1453593600000, 32400000, 55.0000],
      [1453593600000, 36000000, 58.0000],
      [1453593600000, 39600000, 61.0000],
      [1453593600000, 43200000, 61.0000],
      [1453593600000, 46800000, 61.0000],
      [1453593600000, 50400000, 61.0000],
      [1453593600000, 54000000, 59.0000],
      [1453593600000, 57600000, 60.0000],
      [1453593600000, 61200000, 62.0000],
      [1453593600000, 64800000, 63.0000],
      [1453593600000, 68400000, 67.0000],
      [1453593600000, 72000000, 62.0000],
      [1453593600000, 75600000, 63.0000],
      [1453593600000, 79200000, 65.0000],
      [1453593600000, 82800000, 65.0000]
    ]
  };

  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'heatmap',
      marginTop: 40,
      marginBottom: 80,
      plotBorderWidth: 1
    },

    title: {
      text: 'My Title'
    },

    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },

    yAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.value);
        }
      }
    },

    colorAxis: {
      min: 0,
      stops: [
        [0, '#04006D'],
        [0.33, '#119E00'],
        [0.67, '#FFBF00'],
        [1, '#F20011']
      ]
    },

    legend: {
      align: 'right',
      layout: 'vertical',
      margin: 0,
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 25,
      symbolHeight: 280
    },

    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.point.value + '</b>';
      }
    },

    series: [{
      colsize: 86400000,
      rowsize: 3600000,
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: json.Data
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: If you increase all data points values for half rowsize, then all points will be on grid lines and aligned to ticks - https://jsfiddle.net/h2zb2tos/6/ Is this what you are trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `y` value to your `yAxis` labels as follows:

```
yAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.value);
    },
    y: 20
  }
},
```

This will result in the following change to your label:

[image]

Here's a modified fiddle for your reference: https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/h2zb2tos/4/

Please let me know if this helps with your question!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Although that does answer my question, I think it's not quite solving the problem.  I've updated the fiddle to show how the y-axis is behaving if I the heatmap boxs are thinner.  https://jsfiddle.net/h2zb2tos/5/ and you see that the axis lines do not line up with the bottom of the boxes. I'll update my question to highlight this.  Again thanks for help so far.

Comment: Yes, with that solution, you would have to adjust that y value according to the height of your rows. Although while that can potentially solve the label issue, it doesn't fix the actual tick/grid line position, which is really what is driving this issue.